# RegEx for validating integers or float with two decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm willing to get a `regexp` to allow the following price formats below (this is a **string** in a form)

**ALLOW**

- (any price without decimals. can be `[0-9]` 1 or more times)
- ,# (any price with a single decimal)
- ,## (any price with two decimals)

**DON'T ALLOW**

- Anything else... For example:
- 5,555... (3 decmails or longer)
- Whatever string that contains more than 1 comma
- Whatever string that contains any char that it's not a DIGIT
- ETC

So far I got this:

`/^[0-9]+(,[0-9][0-9]?)?$/`

It seems to be working. But is it really doing what I want?

```js
const priceRegex = /^[0-9]+(,[0-9][0-9]?)?$/;

const span1 = document.getElementById('span1');
const span2 = document.getElementById('span2');
const span3 = document.getElementById('span3');
const span4 = document.getElementById('span4');
const span5 = document.getElementById('span5');
const span6 = document.getElementById('span6');
const span7 = document.getElementById('span7');
const span8 = document.getElementById('span8');
const span9 = document.getElementById('span9');
const span10 = document.getElementById('span10');
const span11 = document.getElementById('span11');
const span12 = document.getElementById('span12');
const span13 = document.getElementById('span13');

span1.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span2.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span3.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,55') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';

span4.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span5.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,555') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span6.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,5555') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';

span7.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('a') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span8.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5a') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span9.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('a5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';

span10.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('a,5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span11.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5,a') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span12.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('a5,5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
span13.innerHTML = priceRegex.test('5a,5') ? ' IS VALID' : ' IS NOT VALID';
```

```css
div {
  color: black;
}

span {
  color: blue;
}

.notValid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>5<span id="span1"></span><div>
<div>5,5<span id="span2"></span></div>
<div>5,55<span id="span3"></span></div>

<br/>

<div>5,<span id="span4" class="notValid"></span><div>
<div>5,555<span id="span5" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>5,5555<span id="span6" class="notValid"></span></div>

<div>a<span id="span7" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>5a<span id="span8" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>a5<span id="span9" class="notValid"></span></div>
 
<div>a,5<span id="span10" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>5,a<span id="span11" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>a5,5<span id="span12" class="notValid"></span></div>
<div>5a,5<span id="span13" class="notValid"></span></div>
```

Comment: It works...in the sense that it covers the requirements you've put forward. I don't know if there are other situations that might trip up your regex, e.g., can there be a space before the number? After the number? Can you have a negative value `-1,23`? Can you have a `+1,23`? Can you have `1.23` - with a dot? What happens if something is *not* a price but happens to match the format?

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to allow spaces nor negative values. It just need to match the format of a whole number with 0, 1 or 2 decimals. What I got so far is good enough?

Comment: Yes, it should be. The only *minor* problem I can see is `5,0` and `5,00` - if you consider those valid and don't require them to be truncated, then it's fine.

Comment: Thanks! They are fine both ways. Truncated or not. I'll convert to a number with `parseFloat()` before saving to the database.

Comment: word of caution - `parseFloat` wouldn't like the comma. It expects a dot, so you might need to replace before parsing.

Comment: You are right. Thak you for that! Will do that immediately.

Comment: You regex works fine, don't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we would likely start with two simple expressions, then join them with a logical OR, maybe something similar to:

```
^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+,[0-9]{1,2}$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/CKH7J0/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+,[0-9]{1,2}$/gm;
const str = `5
5,5
5,55

5,
5,555
5,5555
a
5a
a5
a,5
5,a
a5,5
5a,5`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CKH7J0/1/).